# Fix the relative layout at the bottom of the page programatically

Tags: android, android-layout

I have created a scrollView that contains all the layout of my activity. Inside the scrollview i create a linear layout with the vertical orientation, and inside it, with a for-loop, i create some relative layouts that contains images and textview. I need the scrollview because in some moments i can have many images inside the layout and the screen need to be scrolled.
This is ok, all works correctly. My problem is after. As you can see at the bottom of the code, i create the last relative layout that contains a simple button. My problem is that this layout doesn't stay at the bottom of the page, but it move itself up and down in relations to the screen. So if there is only one image for example, the last relative layout goes at the top of the page, attached to the image. If there are many images it is at the bottom of the page.
What i want to do is that the last relative layout stay always at the bottom of the page, also if there is only one image inside the screen.
How can i modify my code for accomplish my objective?

```
            //SCROLL VIEW
            ScrollView scrollView = new ScrollView(this); //create a new scrollView
            scrollView.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.background)); //give the background gradient
            scrollView.setLayoutParams(new ScrollView.LayoutParams(ScrollView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, //set the main params about the dynamic size of the scrollView
                                                         ScrollView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
            scrollView.setPadding(0, 20, 0, 0);

            //LINEAR LAYOUT
            LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this); //create a new linearLayout
            linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL); //set the layout orientation
            linearLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            for (i=0; i<= 3; i++) {

                //RELATIVE LAYOUT
                RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this); //create a new relative layout
                relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, //set main params about the width and height
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
                relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.grayColor)); //set background color
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams relativeParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                relativeParams.setMargins(20, 20, 20, 0);
                relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(relativeParams); //set declared params about layout to the relativeLayout
                relativeLayout.requestLayout();

                //IMAGE VIEW
                ImageView selectedPhoto = new ImageView(this); //create a new imageView
                //imageView code here

                //TEXT VIEWS
                TextView numberCopies = new TextView(this); //create new TextView
                numberCopies.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                numberCopies.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER); //set position to the center in confront to the parent
                                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParamsNumberCopies = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) numberCopies.getLayoutParams();
                layoutParamsNumberCopies.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL); //add a rule to the layout params. We put his position at the horizontal center of the relative layout
                numberCopies.setLayoutParams(layoutParamsNumberCopies); //set the layout rules to the textView

                TextView priceCopies = new TextView(this);
                priceCopies.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                priceCopies.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                numberCopies.setPadding(25, 25, 25, 25);
                priceCopies.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.redColor));

               RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParamsPriceCopies = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) priceCopies.getLayoutParams();
                layoutParamsPriceCopies.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
                layoutParamsPriceCopies.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
                priceCopies.setLayoutParams(layoutParamsPriceCopies);

                relativeLayout.addView(selectedPhoto);
                relativeLayout.addView(numberCopies);
                relativeLayout.addView(priceCopies);
                linearLayout.addView(relativeLayout);
            }

            //RELATIVE LAYOUT
            RelativeLayout relativeLayoutOpenButton = new RelativeLayout(this); //create a new relative layout for add the main buttons
            relativeLayoutOpenButton.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, //add the params for the width and height
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            relativeLayoutOpenButton.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blackColor)); //set the black background
            relativeLayoutOpenButton.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10); //set the padding
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams relativeParamsOpenButton = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            relativeParamsOpenButton.setMargins(0, 20, 0, 0); //put a top margin for separate the black bar from the last image line
            relativeParamsOpenButton.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM; //set the gravity to the bottom
            relativeLayoutOpenButton.setLayoutParams(relativeParamsOpenButton);
            relativeLayoutOpenButton.requestLayout();

            Button confirmButton = new Button(this); //create a new button
            //code button here
            relativeLayoutOpenButton.addView(confirmButton); //add the button to the view

            scrollView.addView(linearLayout);
            setContentView(scrollView);
        }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can have a relative layout  that inside of it you should place your scrollview and button.botton in bottom and scrollview in top of your relative layout.if you do it you will have always button in bottom of screen

```
<RelativeLayout>
<ScrollView> <!--set scrollview in top of relativelayout and top of button -->
<LinearLayout>
.
.
.
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<Button/> <!--set button in buttom of relativelayout-->
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: i'm sorry but i don't have understood correctly. Can you please explain better?

Comment: you should have a RelativeLayout in your main  layout and then in it place your scrollview and button in place that you want.you should place button in outside of scrollview and inside this relativelayout and buttom of it